# How to compute the similarity between lists of features?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I have users and resources. Each resource is described by a set of features and each user is related to a different set of resources. In my particular case, the resources are web pages, and the features information about the location of the visit, the time of the visit, the number of visit etc, which are tied to a specific user each time.

I want to get a similarity measure between my users regarding those features but I can't find a way to aggregate the resource features together. I've done it with text features, as it is possible to add the documents together and then extract features (say TF-IDF), but I don't know how to proceed with this configuration.

To be as clear as possible, here is what I have:

```
>>> len(user_features)
13 # that's my number of users
>>> user_features[0].shape
(2374, 17) # 2374 documents for this user, and 17 features
```

I'm able to get a similarity matrix **of the documents** using euclidean distances for instance:

```
>>> euclidean_distance(user_features[0], user_features[0])
```

But I don't know how do I compare the users against each other. I should somehow aggregate the features together to end up with a `N_Users X N_Features` matrix, but I don't know how.

Any hints on how to proceed?

---

Some more information about the features I'm using:

The features I have here are not completely fixed. What I've got so far is 13 different features, already aggregated from "views". What I have is standard deviation, mean, etc. for each of the views, in order to have something "flat", to be able to compare them. One of the feature I have is: was the location changed since the last view? And what about one hour ago? Two hours ago?

Comment: Numpy supports more distance metrics than just euclidean distance.  are any of the metrics listed on http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html a better fit for your data?

Comment: My problem is not about which metric should I use but rather what's the way to aggregate this stuff. But thanks for the tip :)

Comment: You say "Each resource is described by a set of features" which suggests that these features are independent from the users, but then give "time of the visit" and "number of visits" as features of a given document/resource -- which sounds like they are dependent on particular visits of a user. Can you clarify a little bit?

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on the feature space more? 1) How many unique features are there in total (aggregated over all users and documents)? 2) How sparse is the feature space (e.g., how do you represent the "time of visit", a different "feature" for each visit with the value of the visiting time?) Or do you have fixed slots for a limited period and put a binary mark for each visit? 3) If you pick two random users user_features[x] and user_features[y] how much overlap do you expect in the documents and the features?

Comment: 4) If you pick two random documents (I understand that a document is a collection of lines coming from all user matrices who have visited the document) how much overlap do you expect between them (in terms of non-zero features)?

Comment: I've edited the question about 1) and 2). 

3) Actually made me realise that I'm not really looking to the right direction to solve my problem. Comparing views will not get me anything useful: I'll get common usage patterns of a browser, which is not what I'm looking for. Thanks for making me realize that.

Comment: You are welcome. Have you seen my answer? When/if you are able to compute document-wise similarity matrices, you should be able to make use of set similarity measures to use the document-user links you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each user is represented as a set of document-interaction vectors you can define the similarity of a pair of users as the similarity of the pair of document-interaction vector sets that represent the users.

You say you can get a similarity matrix of the documents. Then assume that user U1 visited documents D1, D2, D3, and user U2 visited documents D1,D3,D4. You would have two sets of vectors S1 = {U1(D1), U1(D2), U1(D3)} for user 1 and S2 = {U2(D1), U2(D3), U2(D4)}. Note that because each user's interaction with a document is different they are represented as such. If I understand correctly, the elements of these sets should correspond to the respective lines in the matrix of each user.

The similarity between these two sets can be computed in many different ways. One option is the average pair-wise similarity: You iterate over all pairings of the elements from each set, compute the document similarity of the pair, and average over all pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mean of the features in each user's set of resources seems a natural way to summarize a user. `numpy.mean` with an appropriate `axis` argument should get you the mean, then compute the Euclidean distance between the resulting "user vectors" (of length n_features) as you did before between document vectors.

Comment: I hope that's not the only solution, as it seems to me that only relying on the means makes me lose a lot of information for later comparison.

I'll try it anyway and see how this ends up

Comment: @Alexis: it's not the only solution, but it's a very fast one, running in O(n) time. Instead of the mean, you can also take the sum, which is similar to concatenating all documents per user, except that the idf weighting is different.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at creating multiple dimensions of documents, so those documents that are visited at certain times of day, divide up by morning and night, and then plot users that are nite owls and early birds.

With any number of dimensions you can create a matrix of users, and use distance between users to help.

Comment: Is it even possible to compare users that are not in the same dimension? How do you do this?