# Similarity of lists in Python - comparing customers according to their features

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, similarity

I have a list of customers and features in the following format:

```
UserID, Feature1, Feature2, Feature3, Feature4
```

So I have a list -- called "Customers" -- and it looks like this:

```
[
['975676924', '1345207523', '-1953633084', '-2041119774', '587903155'], 
['1619201613', '-1384105381', '1433106581', '1445361759', '587903155'], 
['-1470352544', '-1068707556', '-1002282042', '-563691616', '587903155'], 
['-1958275692', '-739953679', '69580355', '-481818422', '587903155'],
['1619201613', '-739953679', '-1002282042', '-481818422', '587903155']
]
```

Each line is a transaction with specific characteristics. The first element in each line is the UserID (customer) doing that transaction. Therefore, `Customers[1]` gives the second line and `Customers[1][0]` gives the UserID of that line (`1619201613`).

The UserIDs can be repeated in other lines (new transactions), as repeat customers will be appended to the list. So, for instance, note that `Customers[4][0]` gives the same UserID (`1619201613`), but the features of `Customers[4]` are not the same as that of `Customers[1]` -- i.e., the customer came back and bought a different product with different features.

So here's the central question: How do I *efficiently* calculate similarity between every two *distinct* customers in my list?
I think the question should actually be split into two different questions / tasks:

1. Grouping together the distinct UserIDs. So the first question is: How do I efficiently put together all the distinct features of a single UserID, so that, for instance, `Customers[1]` and `Customers[4]` are put into a single new line (new list?) of the form:
   `['1619201613', '-1384105381', '1433106581', '1445361759', '587903155', '-739953679', '-1002282042', '-481818422']`
2. Finding similarity of Customers via their transactions. So the second question is: How do I efficiently evaluate a similarity function in `[0,1]` that tells me if two distinct customers are interested in the same stuff?

---

PS. Some additional notes:

1. The order of the features does not matter, as they are hashed and uniquely identified.
2. The cardinality of the features does not matter either, i.e., we don't care if the same feature appears twice or three times for the same UserID.
3. The end-result of this whole thing is to be able to get a network of customers, where the UserIDs are nodes and the edges between them are weighted by the similarity score.
4. I tend to prefer cosine similarity, or Jaccard index, but open to alternatives.
5. I need speed and scalability, even if that sacrifices some accuracy, to a small degree of course.
6. I have checked previous questions thoroughly - e.g., the following are not relevant: [Calculating the similarity of two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709693/calculating-the-similarity-of-two-lists); [Python Checking Multiple Lists For Similarities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451052/python-checking-multiple-lists-for-similarities); [How to compute the similarity between lists of features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042150/how-to-compute-the-similarity-between-lists-of-features)

Comment: For a complete question you should show your current attempt

Comment: I haven't been able to make a first attempt, jamylak. I'm relatively new to Python and I am using it in this context so as to scale up to hundreds of thousands of users and process them as networks (then use NetworkX, with which I am a bit more familiar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers part one of your question:

```
raw_data = [
['975676924', '1345207523', '-1953633084', '-2041119774', '587903155'],
['1619201613', '-1384105381', '1433106581', '1445361759', '587903155'],
['-1470352544', '-1068707556', '-1002282042', '-563691616', '587903155'],
['-1958275692', '-739953679', '69580355', '-481818422', '587903155'],
['1619201613', '-739953679', '-1002282042', '-481818422', '587903155']
]

import collections
data = collections.defaultdict(list)

for line in raw_data:
    data[line[0]].extend(line[1:])
```

Now you have a dictionary with the id as key:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
'1619201613': 
         ['-1384105381', '1433106581', '1445361759', '587903155',
          '-739953679', '-1002282042', '-481818422', '587903155'],  
'-1470352544': 
         ['-1068707556', '-1002282042', '-563691616', '587903155'], 
 '975676924': 
        ['1345207523', '-1953633084', '-2041119774', '587903155'],
 '-1958275692':
         ['-739953679', '69580355', '-481818422', '587903155']})
```

You will get the desired list by rearranging:

```
data_list = [[key] + value for key, value in data.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Group the distinct User assuming your list named l

```
summary = {}  # init a map for group
for entry in l:
    if summary[entry[0]]:
        summary[entry[0]] += entry[1:]
    else:
        summary[entry[0]] = entry[1:]

# delete duplicate element
for s in summary:
    summary[s] = [int(x) for x in list(set(summary[s]))]
```

Step 2: Build a network, actually a two-dimensional array, and calculate the similarity between different users.

```
# the row and column number of this array
cnt = len(summary) 
network = [[0] * cnt] * cnt

index = [x for x in summary]
for x, xvalue in enumerate(index):
    for y, yvalue in enumerate(index):
        common = len(set(summary[xvalue]) & set(summary[yvalue]))
        network[x][y] = common
```

Now network is the a two-dimensional array, containing the common item number between each UserID.

For example, your list is:

```
[['100', '2', '3','4'],
 ['110', '2', '5', '6'],
 ['120', '6', '3', '4']]
```

Then network is:

```
[[3, 1, 2],
 [1, 3, 1],
 [2, 1, 3]]
```

Some code is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451052/python-checking-multiple-lists-for-similarities)

Comment: Thanks Roger. The first step produces an empty dictionary (for summary). The second one (adapted to take the dictionary from the second answer by Mike) produces a NxN table, but it doesn't look right to me - there is a column all 0's and the diagonal is not always equal to 1. Perhaps I misread your answer of course!

Comment: Sorry. The first step is wrong, I have fixed it. And network generated in second step tells how many items both bought by two users. For instance, element in [0,1] is 1, which means User0 and User1 bought 1 same item. If the value is 0, then these two users have no same item. You could add 1 to every element to make there's no 0 in the matrix.

Comment: Thanks Roger - first part now works fine with small datasets (up to a few 10k of lines) but struggles with > 1 million lines. I get "Out of Memory" in the bigger case. I saw somewhere else (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283220/memory-error-in-python) that it is possible to use a baffer?? Do you know about this?

Comment: Which statement cause out of memory?

Comment: Out of Memory is caused by the for loop (the first one, which builds up "summary")

Comment: buffer type in python views an object as byte array. In your case, it's a string array, whose string's length is not determined (right?). I think it's not suitable to use buffer here. Instead, you could divide the huge list into smaller parts and produce the network in several steps.